# How to get text data from form to iframe via php file?

Tags: php, forms, iframe

So I have a form:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Post a comment:</legend>


<form target="forum" method="post" action="forum.php">    

//Targeting the iframe in my form (`<form target="forum"`) & Submitting the form to my PHP file (`action="forum.php"`) 

                Name: <br />
        <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
                Subject:<br />
        <input type="text" name="subject" size="50"/><br />
                Comment:<br />
<textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="100">Hello,</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then I want to take the **text data** (name, subject and comment) and put that **into an iframe** on the **click of a button** `<input type="submit" value="Send" />`...

The **iframe is on the same page as the form** (below it) and looks like this...

```
<iframe name="forum" src="forum.php" 
width="900" height="500" ></iframe>
```

Once the text data has been inputted I wanted the iframe to store that data there permanently. Basically like a forum within an iframe.

How do I process the form in the php file and spit out the result into the iframe?

Comment: You said iframe, which immediately makes me think this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

make the source of the iframe forum.php and include the parameters in the URL ? use $_GET in PHP to get the parameters ?

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="forum.php?fname=blah&subject=blah"></iframe>
```

So you would use javascript to change the src of the iFrame on the submit of the form :

```
document.getElementById['myiframe'].src = "forum.php?fname=blah&subject=blah";
```

then in PHP get the variables and do what you need todo with them to produce the desired output:

```
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$subject = $_GET['subject'];
// do some processing
```

Comment: @user1048885 no probs - please make sure you start to accept answers to your questions - there is a tick to the left of the answers - tick the one that helped resolve your question .....